# shows an empty page and says you should login first to use the sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, nopcommerce

hi i am trying to integrating paypal standard in nop commerce 2.4. after i set required things in admin panel, when i don't use sandbox, the cart shows up alright. but, when i enabled "use sand box" and after proceeding to payment for paypal, the site redirect to paypal to show the paypal cart, it shows an empty page and says you should login first to use the sandbox, a message like that. but when I put the site in live mode, the redirect loads the paypal checkout page as usual. i don't understand what's the problem.

i searched the internet for past few days and i am stuck in the situation.. please help me out.

as i am not rep 10 i can't upload image: 
[please see the link for the screen appears for my cart](http://www.luminowebdesign.com/uploads/PayPal-Sandbox-before-login__st.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set your cart to the sandbox, this is used for testing.  You would need to set up a developer account with PayPal at [PayPal's Developer Site](http://www.developer.paypal.com).  Once you have your developer account set up, you need to set up a test sandbox seller and buyer account.  Then you would configure your shopping cart with your sandbox acct credentials if you are going to be testing with the sandbox.  Then in a separate tab, log into [PayPal's Developer Account](http://www.developer.paypal.com) if you are not already logged in.  Then in a different tab, you can go through and test your checkout with the sandbox.